# GPT4の搭載方法

Tags: chatgpt

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]最近GPTを搭載したアプリケーションが増えてますがあれはどうやって搭載してるんですか？cd [gptのファイル名]にrunって感じなんですか？

Answer (score 2):

APIを利用すれば良いかと思います。

[GPT-4のAPIが7月6日より誰でも利用可能と一般公開！ウェイトリスト不要に](https://auto-worker.com/blog/?p=7919)
[documents](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/gpt/faq)

Comment: あー成る程。API...でもGPTのAPIって金かかるんじゃないですか？

Comment: 詳細についてはOpenAIのドキュメントを参照ください。ところで有料か無料かは質問内容とどう関係していますでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。ちょっとずれましたね。ではGitからGPTをインストールできるって話を聞いたのですがそれは可能ですか？

Comment: 「GitからGPTをインストールできるって話を聞いた」とのことですが、どこで（サイト？誰かから？）聞いたのでしょうか？何かエビデンス（書籍やサイトなど）がある話であれば新たに質問を立てられた方が有識者からの回答を得られるかと思います。

Comment: 確か3日前だったのでよく覚えていませんがApplication development How to install gpt?みたいなこと打ち込んだら出てきた気がします。

Comment: 写真ってどうやって送ればいいですか？

Comment: 「確か3日前だったのでよく覚えていませんが」がブラウザで検索したのであれば、ブラウザの履歴に残っていませんか？「GitからGPTをインストールできるって話を聞いた」については私は存じないので新規に質問されるのが良いかと思います。

Comment: 「写真ってどうやって送ればいいですか？」が質問に画像を掲載したいという意味であれば、質問を入力する画面で「画像」ボタンをクリックすれば良いです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。変えました。